# Change directory with popen

Tags: c, popen, cd

I'm able to use `popen` to run just about any program, but apparently not `cd`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    FILE *fp = popen("cd", "w");
    pclose(fp);
}
```

I'd expect that to change directory to home but nothing happens. Changing to "r", or changing to e.g. "cd ~", "cd /", does not help. Using `system` has about the same result, i.e. works for anything but `cd`. So how is it done? The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636314/stay-in-directory-with-popen) don't work for me. Thank you.

Comment: To change working dir of the process use `chdir()` 

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html

Comment: ^ If on a POSIX system...

Comment: I think my answer is given in the question "linked" by @ephemient, which I hadn't seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is generally a shell internal command, NOT an executable.

Even if it were, in general no process can change another process's working directory, so it would change the cwd for the "cd" process and then upon exit it'd be gone.

Comment: `cd` is practically always a shell builtin. Can you name any implementation where it is not?

Comment: No, but I don't know every implementation under the sun so I went with a safer answer of "generally" instead of "always."